# log4j RollingFileAppender creates file but leaves it empty

Tags: java, spring, log4j

I have a log4j.properties file:

```
log4j.logger.com.mypackage=debug, R, stdout

log4j.appender.stdout=org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender
log4j.appender.stdout.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.stdout.layout.ConversionPattern=%d [%t] %-5p %c - %m%n

log4j.appender.R=org.apache.log4j.RollingFileAppender
log4j.appender.R.File=myapplication.log
log4j.appender.R.MaxFileSize=10MB
log4j.appender.R.MaxBackupIndex=10 
log4j.appender.R.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.R.layout.ConversionPattern=%p %t %c - %m%n
```

logging into stdout works fine, if I change "debug" in the first line to "error" I get only the error msgs in stdout.

the myapplication.log gets created but it's empty. If I remove the "R" from the first line, the file will not be created.

ll shows the file as

```
-rw-r--r--  1 <myname>  staff     0B Oct 28 16:26 myapplication.log
```

I did a chmod 777 myapplication.log but that didn't help.

I'm on OS X 10.11.1 using STS 3.6.4

I searched google and stackoverflow but couldn't find a solution so far.

edit:
I changed the line

```
log4j.logger.com.mypackage=debug, R, stdout
```

to

```
log4j.rootLogger=debug, R, stdout
```

Now the messages are written into the file, but only those that are not from mypackage.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I changed the file location to

```
log4j.appender.R.File=${catalina.home}/logs/myapplication.log
```

now I get my logging messages written into the file.

I have no idea why this work but write to myapplication.log (without a path) writes only log messages from other libraries in there.

Answer (score 0):

I've landed here looking for an answer to a similar problem. In my case, after making the first roll, the second file was being generated empty. My issue was that I was missing this sentence in my config:
`log4j.appender.R.MaxBackupIndex=10`